# What is the proper way to let non-sudo users mount their windows drives to their home directories of an ubuntu machine?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, mount

We have an ubuntu machine installed with specific versions of development tools and packages that we don't want them to be upgraded accidentally.

We want to let developers mounting their windows drives to their own home directories on the ubuntu, so that they can build their own code using the build environment.

Is it possible to not making these users sudo-ers but still be able to mount their drives?

Comment: Use a better code management strategy ..? Eg. a build server (or really any automated process) pulling from committed work.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Yea, we already have a build system.  We use it for building our actual commits.  But our code size is big so it takes long time for the build agent to check out all the code each time and build.  The ubuntu machine, on the other hand, is for debugging so it requires frequent changes and rebuild.

Comment: Do you mean mounting a drive from a *remote* system, mounting another internal drive on the *same* system, or mounting an *external* drive?

Comment: I mean mounting a folder or an internal drive from another desktop machine (likely windows) to the ubuntu machine.  The flow is that each developers make changes in their own desktops.  When ready, mount their internal folder of code to the ubuntu machine for building - read/write through network.  The incremental build time is not too bad because only few modified files need to be rebuilt.

Comment: Did you consider https://www.docker.com/ ? You can share folders on the buildserver and the developers can sudo in their own environment. Their pending changes get lost when the image is shutdown, using git (next comment) would be my choice.

Comment: When you split your project in several modules, and use maven to define dependencies in the pom.xml will give smaller checkout times and better control. You can combine this with git. Only the module that is changed need to be checked out and compiled everytime, the targets of the other modules can be pulled (jar files, generated source, whatever)

Comment: Thanks, I will check them out.